# How to create radio buttons dynamically with array elements as label for buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create radio buttons according to the elements of array that i am calling from database. and this elements should be use as label for each radio button. How i can code for it. I am calling 6 element as username suggestion. and when a guest select any of button then that label for particular button will replace the input name type by guest. Thank You

Comment: What are your attempts so far?

Comment: Show example of array from database and result that you expect.

Comment: I know how to create radio buttons dynamically. but i have no idea that how i can create it with different labels. Like I type a name in input "Michael".. so by change event.. this value is going to database where it is exist or not. If this value is exist then i will get array {"Michael5678" , "Michael5128", "Michael2278" , "Michael2345 , "Michael5611" , "Michael9856"}. And i have to display this values as username suggestion with radio buttion. So if a guest will select any of value then it will replace the input value in field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function showSuggestions() {
  var usernames = [
    'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'
  ];
  
  var result = $('#result');
  result.html('');

  for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    result.append('<label><input type="radio" name="usernames" value="' + usernames[i] + '" /> ' + usernames[i] + '</label>');
  } 
}
                      
$('button').click(showSuggestions);

$('#result').on('change', 'input', function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  if (elem.is(':checked')) {
    $('#search').val(elem.val());
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display:block;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" type="search" /><button>Search</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: thank you Sir. i try it by implement it with my code. thanks again. Sir can you suggest me how i can display this element in vertical alignment

Comment: thank you. i almost done everything. But i dont know .. why i am getting problem to replacing the text. this last function is not working and not giving any check value on console the elem.val() .. i try this code in js fiddle where it is working and console all this array element on checked. But my code is not working on checked. what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: yeah but you will not able to see array. that i am calling from database. wait i should make a jsfiddle. And thank you for your concern

Comment: Sir sorry. I thought this is the method you are calling in showSuggestion function. But now i find that it was different function. i call it and now everything is working. thank you sir again